# Python, finding all local maxima of array, adjusting for flaws in measurement

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

i'm trying to get the maximum points in a one dimensional array, where it makes several curves. To do this i use `scipy.signal.argrelextrema`, along with `np.greater`. Give here where the array is `y`:

```
argrelextrema(y, np.greater)
```

The issue is, that this one dimensional data has inaccuracies due to the way the data for `y` was gathered. And so, there's a lot of "false positives" at the bottom of the curve, where there technically is a maxima at the bottom because of one value being bigger than the surrounding ones.

For reference, here's y, over x which is just the index of each y value, to demonstrate the array i'm working with. The inaccuracies at the bottom is not visible. Ignore axises, used what i had in the code.

[image: y]

Also, here's the result of me using the found maxima to calculate a value, as seen this is not wanted, as the expected result should have been a smooth falling curve. The graph was made with one point for each maxima, in an increasing order. And it's clearly wrong, as one can observe from the actual graph.

[image: results]

So, what's the best solution to avoid shis? I failed to find something that could approximate the graph in a good enough manner for me the be able to use it. I looked into smoothening, but the methods i found, like `savgol_filter` from `scipy.signal`, was something i could not understand.

The current solution was to ignore values of y that were below 5, which was roughly a bit over the bottom of the curve, but not an ideal solution at all.

**Update:**

Found out `find_peaks_cwt` from `scipy.signal` works for this too. It's a tad more complex as i have absolutely no clue how most of it works, even after reading up on it a bit. However, i managed to make a slightly better graph, i think, using: `find_peaks_cwt(y, [3], noise_perc=2)` However, the result seen below, is only a result of me dropping noise from 10 to 2, without really knowing how that affects the result.

[image]

Edit: 
Here's is the 1D-array i'm working on: https://pastebin.com/GZrBBRce
Sorry for bad representation, but each line is the next value in the list. It's a bit large.

Edit: Minimum working examplem, y is from the pastebin, a bit large to include in minimum working example:

```
energy = []
for i in find_peaks_cwt(y, [3],noise_perc=2):
    energy.append(y[i])
plt.plot([i for i in range(len(energy))], energy)
plt.show()
```

This was made with some guessing, and the result is seen in the last image in this question.

**Update 2:** Further progress, i smoothed out the y function using `numpy.polyfit` with a 15 degree approximation. It's surprisingly accurate. And since that is smooth, i can revert to the first function `argrelextrema(y, np.greater)`, and it's gives me a pretty decent answer as well as not including false positives, as seen in the above graphs. (I got 30-40 maximas, when my graph only has a little above 20 of them.)

I'll let it stand a bit, before marking solved, in case anyone want to have a go at a better solution and approximating the graph with `numpy.polyfit`. However this solved the issue for my usecase.

Comment: Can you somehow include your data, at least part of it or function that create it.

Comment: Have you considered providing a minimal working example?

Comment: @norok2 I added a link to pastebin, with a list, where each value is on a new line. This is one of the ones i'm working on.

Comment: @ChaosPredictor, Added list which i'm working with.

Comment: I edited my answer to add one way of doing it with `find_peaks_cwt()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use: `scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt()`.

From its documentation:

> Attempt to find the peaks in a 1-D array.
>
> The general approach is to smooth vector by convolving it with wavelet(width) for each width in widths. Relative maxima which appear at enough length scales, and with sufficiently high SNR, are accepted.

**UPDATE** (with actual data)

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import scipy.signal

y_arr = np.loadtxt('/home/raid1/metere/Downloads/1d_array.txt')
print('array size: ', y_arr.shape)

arr_size = len(y_arr)
expected_num = 30

expected_width = arr_size // expected_num // 2
print('expected width of peaks: ', expected_width)

peaks = sp.signal.find_peaks_cwt(y_arr, np.linspace(2, expected_width, 10))

print('num peaks: ', len(peaks))
print('peaks: ', peaks)

plt.plot(y_arr)
for peak in peaks:
    plt.axvline(peak)
plt.show()
```

This can probably tweaked further, for example to increase the accuracy.

Comment: I just made an edit for that one. (Always discover stuff like it, after making these questions...)

Comment: without some data it is actually very difficult to help you further.

Comment: This works really well, it detects the same amount of peaks as my approximation did, though the overall values are a bit higher, though i can't really tell if that's more accurate or not.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not too big array the simplest way that I can think right now is just by one loop on the array's value. Somethong like:

if ar[i-1] < ar[i] & ar[i] > ar[i+1]

Add a[i] to maxArray.

You just need to check if ar[i] != ar[i+1]. In case that it equal, you should take the first or that value or the eqauls values.

Edit:

```
count=1
leng=len(list1)-1
while count < leng:
    count=count+1
    if ((list1[count-1] < list1[count]) & (list1[count] > list1[count+1])):
        print list1[count]


21.55854026
4.205178829
16.6062412
16.60490417
13.14358751
11.76675489
10.71131948
10.34922208
9.703966466
4.440605216
9.557176225
9.163999162
4.530660664
9.067259599
4.482917884
8.628552441
4.443787789
8.340760319
7.9779415
4.411471328
4.415029139
7.840661767
7.858075487
4.413923668
7.555398794
7.533918443
4.445146914
7.58446368
7.56834833
7.264249919
7.34901701
7.349173404
7.315796894
7.235120197
4.577840109
7.24188544
7.243943576
7.205527364
4.480817125
4.483523464
4.526264151
6.90592723
6.903067763
6.905932124
4.513352307
4.464000858
6.848673936
6.831810008
6.819620162
4.485243384
6.606738091
```

Your data a bit noisy. so I got some "additional" values.

**EDIT 2:**

so you can add a filter, I sure that you can find a better way to do it but the simplest for me now is:

```
list2=[]
count=3
leng=len(list1)-4
while count < leng:
    count=count+1
    avr=(list1[count-3]+list1[count-2]+list1[count-1]+list1[count]+list1[count+1]+list1[count+2]+list1[count+3])/7
    list2.append(avr)

count=1
leng=len(list2)-2
while count < leng:
    count=count+1
    if ((list2[count-1] < list2[count]) & (list2[count] > list2[count+1])):
        print list2[count]

21.5255838514
16.5808501743
13.1294409014
11.75618281
10.7026162129
10.3274025343
9.68175366729
9.53899509229
9.15257714671
9.06056034386
8.615976868
8.33681455
7.971226556
7.84655894214
7.54856005157
7.57721360586
7.34372518657
7.23259654857
6.90384834786
6.83781572657
```

Comment: It also falls prey to the same issue i have, in that i have smaller peaks that will trigger a point, where i don't want. The solution would work, along with others, once the curve i work on is perfectly smooth (or, no micropeaks at least.)

Comment: @Thomasedv - filter added (edit2), it's far a way from been an elegant solution, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks for this, although it seems to miss one or two points for some reason, it's a very close result. (I think the first and last piece of the graph) Though i decided to go with the other answer since it seems a bit closer to what i expected. But thanks for this approach, i know it can use this in the future if i need to on data that's very noisy.